# Как реализовать логированние для BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, java

Прям стыдно уже об этом писать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить работу BroadcastReceiver логгированием. Вставляю код сразу после  метода onReceive, красным подчеркивает getPackageManager

Вот класс ресивера

```
      public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      private static final String SMS_REC_ACTION =   "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
      private static final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
      @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intent1, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Receiver name: " + info.activityInfo.name+ "; priority= " + info.priority);
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equals(SmsReceiver.SMS_REC_ACTION)){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                sb.append("\nAdres: " + smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress());
                sb.append("\nAdres: " + smsMessage.getMessageBody());
                }
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sms Resiver mesage" + sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}}
```

Как мне уже объяснили у меня  "провалился" Toast, мне надо это логированием проверить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это так:

```
private final static String TAG=SmsReceiver.class.getName();
//blah-blah

public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
   //blah-blah
    Log.i(TAG, "Ye-ye, receiver started!");
    Log.i(TAG, "Intent="+intent.toString()+ " with action="+intent.getAction());
}
```

Далее идете в логи отображаемые вашим Eclipse (или что там у вас) и включаете фильтр на теги "SmsReceiver" - и смотрите работает ваш ресивер или нет.

Comment: С логами разобрался. Вы тут наверное самый опытный, хотел у вас узнать. Мне тут выслали код ресивера, проверил работает на 4.3, но дело в том, что там присутствует файл Активити и в манифесте он прописан. В нем два метода onCreate и onCreateOptionsMenu Т.е. есть ярлык во вкладке приложения, его можно там запсутить, и при запуске  появляется окно Активити. В нем ничего нет, но на мой взгляд оно лишнее. Так вот вопрос без класса Майн..., который наследуется от Активити возможен запуск ресивера, и его корректная работа? Чтобы не было этого окна. Если что, просьба не нервничать. Я только новичок.

Comment: Оформляйте в виде вопроса

Comment: Можете не отвечать, уже сделал без активити, убрал просто его из манифеста, Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Спасибо за разрешение :) То что вы сделали это не совсем айс. При попытке открытия `Activity` - это вызовет крах системы (поскольку нет декларации в манифесте). Удачи.

Comment: А мне Активити не надо будет открывать, я из ресивера все в сервис передаю и ресивер закрывается. У меня вообще все в фоне или это не имеет значение?

Answer (score 5):

А вы задавались вопросом, какому классу принадлежит метод `getPackageManager()`?  
так вот, рекомендую вам [почитать](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager())  
А класс [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), как известно, не наследуется от класса [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).
Oт сюда и следует, почему не находит метод `getPackageManager()`.  
В `onReceive()` вам передается `Context`, так вызывайте `context.getPackageManager()`

Comment: Спасибо конечно, по этой ссылке наверно много чего интересного, но я с английским не очень дружу - на уровне on off. Буду дальше читать теорию, думаю осилю Context и ему подобных.

Comment: @FFFNikolay Очень сложно развиваться в программировании без знания английского. А почитывая англ. мануалы, держа под рукой переводчик, это знание можно подтянуть.